# Mezzanine rich text field

Tags: django, sqlite, mezzanine

how to access rich text field as a variable in django template language using in mezzanine CMS

Comment: {{ page.table.content }}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using the RichTextPage model built into Mezzanine, the tag is:

```
{{ page.richtextpage.content }}
```

If you have a custom model called CustomModel descended from Page that has a field called content that uses Mezzanine's RichTextField, the tag is:

```
{{ page.custommodel.content }}
```